# Resolving AliasFor annotation value programatically in Spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have an annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface A {
    Class<?> value();
}
```

and another annotation that uses `@AliasFor`

```
@A (Void.class)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface B {

    @AliasFor(annotation = A.class)
    Class<?> value();
}
```

which is used on class

```
@B(D.class)
public class C implements D {
}
```

If I have an instance of `C`, how can I programatically resolve `A.value()` to `Class<D>`?
I'm trying to synthesise the annotation with `AnnotationUtils` but when I retrieve the value I'm constantly getting `Class<Void>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging around, the answer is that I've used the wrong class. Instead of `AnnotationUtils` it can be done with `AnnotatedElementUtils`:

```
@Test
public void shouldFindAliasedValue() {

    Class<?> actual = AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(C.class, A.class).value();

    then(actual).isEqualTo(D.class);
}
```