# How to create custom @ConditionalOnProperty for simpler usage?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

In a Spring-Boot project, I use `@ConditionalOnProperty` to choose whether some Beans get loaded or not. It looks like the following:

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    prefix = "myservice",
    name = "implversion",
    havingValue = "a"
)
@Service
public class MyServiceImplA implements MyService {
   // ...
}
```

This allows me to choose with specific profiles which Bean should be loaded, for example different implementations of an interface, depending on the value of `myservice.implversion` being `a` or `b` or whatever other value.

I'd like to achieve the same effect with a user-friendlier annotation like such:

```java
@OnMyServiceVersion(value = "a")
@Service
public class MyServiceImplA implements MyService {
   // ...
}
```

How can one do this?

---

I've tried annotating my custom annotation with `@Conditional` and implementing the `Condition` interface but I don't understand how to check properties that way. The Spring-Boot `OnPropertyCondition extends SpringBootCondition` is not `public` so I cannot start from there, and extending annotations isn't allowed, so I'm kind of stuck.

I've also tried the following with no success:

```java
// INVALID CODE, DO NOT USE
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    prefix = "myservice",
    name = "implversion",
    havingValue = OnMyServiceVersion.value()
)
public @interface OnMyServiceVersion {
    String value();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can annotate your `@OnMyServiceVersion` annotation with `@ConditionalOnProperty` and alias the `value` of your annotation to the `havingValue` attribute of `@ConditionalOnProperty`:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myservice", name = "implversion")
public @interface OnMyServiceVersion {

    @AliasFor(annotation = ConditionalOnProperty.class, attribute = "havingValue")
    String value() default "";

}
```

Here's a complete example that shows this in action:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AliasFor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CustomPropertyConditionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CustomPropertyConditionApplication.class, "--myservice.implversion=b");
    }
    
    @Service
    @OnMyServiceVersion("a")
    static class ServiceA {
        
        ServiceA() {
            System.out.println("Service A");
        }
        
    }
    
    @Service
    @OnMyServiceVersion("b")
    static class ServiceB {
        
        ServiceB() {
            System.out.println("Service B");
        }
        
    }
    
    @Documented
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myservice", name = "implversion")
    static @interface OnMyServiceVersion {
        
        @AliasFor(annotation = ConditionalOnProperty.class, attribute = "havingValue")
        String value() default "";
        
    }

}
```

This will output `Service B` when run. If you change the arguments in the main method to `--myservice.implversion=a` it will output `Service A`. If you remove the argument, it won't output either.

Comment: This perfectly does the trick, thanks a lot. One more question if I may ask: is it possible to "transform" the value, say having the custom annotation using an Enum for `value` (e.g. `MyServiceImplementation.IMPL_A`) and translating that to a String (e.g. `a`) for property checking?
EDIT: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39492767/5018771) seems to near the topic but I don't understand it.

Comment: I suspect not. Have you tried?

Comment: I can only achieve this by parsing the properties and annotations "per hand", implementing the `Condition` interface, using `context.getEnvironment().getProperty("myservice.implversion")` and `metadata.getAnnotations().stream().filter(a -> OnMyServiceVersion.class.equals(a.getType())).findFirst().orElseThrow().getEnum("value", MyServiceImplementation.class)`. I can then match the property value and the enum value to decide on the result of the `matches` method but I doubt this is as robust as the `@ConditionalOnProperty` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean(name = "emailNotification")
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "notification", name = "service")
public NotificationSender notificationSender() {
    return new EmailNotification();
}
```

for reference
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty

Comment: Sadly this is not what I am looking for. I know the tutorial you mention, my goal is to "hide" the _prefix_ and _name_ attributes from the annotation user.